# How to call the function of particular library version if we have 2 versions of same library?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

In my project two version of libssl (1.0.2k and 1.1.1i) are linked. Can't remove any of them, because other libraries like libcurl, libunbound depends on libssl1.0.2k.

So I have linked both the version of library in my process but when I called the some function it is calling from libssl1.0.2k not from libssl1.1.1i.
due to library version mismatch getting segfault.

```
#0  0x00007f6104ac5696 in ssl_cert_set1_chain () from /lib64/libssl.so.10
#1  0x00007f610550fe6a in ERR_peek_error () from /opt/runtime/current/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
#2  0x00007f61058e8f70 in SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file () from /opt/runtime/current/lib/libssl.so.1.1
#3  0x0000000003a6699b in evhtp_ssl_init ()
```

How to resolve this crash?

Comment: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH when executing

Comment: how do you load/link those libraries?

Comment: In CentOS/RHEL, openssl uses versioned symbols, so I expect something like this would get you out of your conundrum if it could be applied here. It would cause all the symbols that you're using to bind to the 1.1 version of openssl, while the other libraries would bind to the generic symbol version of openssl (one hopes)

Comment: @stark , I tried to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it didn't help.

Comment: @MarekR, I'm linking like below                             $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/lib/libssl.so.1.1 $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 \
                   $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/libevent/ix64/lib/libevent.so \
                   $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/libevent/ix64/lib/libevent_openssl.so \
                   $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/libevent/ix64/lib/libevent_core.so \
                   $(THIRDPTYBIN_DIR)/libevhtp/ix64/libevhtp.a \
                   -lssl -lcrypto -lunbound -lexpat -lgmp \

Comment: @Petesh I'm not sure how to use the version symbols of openssl, could you please help me me out on that. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be the right time to rebuild everything using OpenSSL-3.0.1

Answer (score 2):

> How to call the function of particular library version if we have 2 versions of same library?

Calling a function from a given library is trivial: use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, but this is the least of your problems.

> In my project two version of libssl (1.0.2k and 1.1.1i) are linked.

This is your problem. *No matter what you try*, this *will not work*<sup>1</sup>. Your program will most likely `SIGSEGV`.

> Can't remove any of them, because other libraries like libcurl, libunbound depends on libssl1.0.2k

To get a *sane* execution environment, you must arrange for a *consistent* set of libraries -- either all depending on `libssl-1.0.2k`, or all depending on `libssl-1.1.1i`.

All of the libraries you listed are open-source, the best solution (if you can't find pre-built ones with whatever version of `libssl` you desire) is to rebuild them.

---

<sup>1</sup>
A possible workaround is to use `dlmopen` and keep the libraries which depend on `libssl-1.0.2k` in a separate linker namespace from the ones which depend on `libssl-1.1.1i`.

This is *not* recommended -- you really need to know what you are doing, and debugging your program will be significantly more difficult.